# ondragstart not triggering in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Hello I'm trying to use the html drag and drop feature with jquery. I generate my draggable (a button) like this

```
$("#tb > tbody > tr").append(($("<td>")).append($("<input/>", {type:"button", id:"bt", draggable:"true", value:"test", class:"bt-test"}))).append($("</td>"));
```

So far, and after reading a bit on the subject, I'm trying to deal with the different events like this :

```
$(document).on("dragstart", ".bt-test", function(evt)
{
    evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", $(this).val());
    alert(evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
    evt.originalEvent.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('dragenter', function(evt){evt.originalEvent.preventDefault();});
$(document).on('dragleave', function(evt){evt.originalEvent.preventDefault();});
$(document).on('dragover', function(evt){evt.originalEvent.preventDefault();});


// still irrelevant at this point
$(document).on("drop", ".btCase", function(evt)
{
    var data = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    $(this).val(data);
    event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

The alert within the dragstart listener shows up just fine on chrome but it doesn't on firefox.

I already tried adding an `ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);"` directly into my button as mentionned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API but the problem remains. I also tried replacing the `event.originalEvent.preventDefault();` with `return false();`

Any tips?

edit : fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/Nn4x2/4/

Comment: Can you provide a working example on JSFiddle or other?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Nn4x2/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with a `div` element, see http://jsfiddle.net/Nn4x2/26/
It seems draggable input buttons are not supported in Firefox. It may be best to use a styled anchor element instead.

This is logged as a Firefox bug for button elements - see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568313

Comment: Yes I saw that; I was just curious of what was the incompatibility. Thanks for the link. I guess i'll use anchors anyway. Thanks