# Prevent Image dragging in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link with background image which is in a carousel. The problem is that whenever the user drags the carousel, the image get dragged instead with a ghost image visible when dragging. This causes inconsistent dragging behaviour for the carousel. I tried using `user-select : none`, but it only works in Chrome and Edge. How do I disable image dragging in Firefox? Adding `draggable="false"` on anchor tag also doesn't work

Run below code in Firefox to test. Try to drag the image and observe the behaviour.

```css
.disable-dragging  {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="disable-dragging" draggable="false"></a>
```

Comment: You can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445158/ondragstart-not-triggering-in-firefox

Comment: @hamid This is not what I asked for. Please read the question carefully before commenting.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the `=` in the HTML attribute

```html
<a href="#" class="disable-dragging" draggable="false"></a>
```

And remove `user-select: none;`

Full working code

```css
.disable-dragging {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  /* user-select: none; */
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="disable-dragging" draggable="false"></a>
```

Update:

As @kaiido said in the comment `user-select` has an influence here.

And is an open issue in firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1376369

Comment: `pointer-events: none` will prevent clicking on the link also, which I cannot do.

Comment: Curious as to why user-select has any influence here... Here is my answer: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1376369

Comment: @VnoitKumar: I fixed the code above, and its working after removing `user-select : none`. However, the same fix is not working on my actual project code. Is there something else other than `user-select` which prevents `draggable="false"` from working in Firefox?

Comment: Can you share me the full code instead of sharing use part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent default action on mousedown event for the image

```
<img src="test.png" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
```

You can disable this for all image using

```
window.onload = function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event, imgs, i;
  
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i].onmousedown = disableDragging;
        }
    }
};
 
function disableDragging(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

In your case you can replace the tag